# Does android wear 2.0 support Intents for waking other standalone app and sharing data?

Tags: android, android-intent, wear-os

i'm trying to find any examples of intent mechanism for sharing data from android wear app. All examples of code with Intent and SEND_TO for smartphone app doesn't work on wear.
Does android wear 2.0 support Intents for waking other standalone app and sharing data? If doesn't - how i can send a file or even message from wear to any user (Email, Telegram, Facebook, Note, anything)?

Comment: [Sending and Receiving Messages on Wear](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html) can be done using [`MessageClient`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageClient). You also need to attach an arbitrary payload (optional) and a path that uniquely identifies the message's action. Check out the in-depth details from the documentation.

Comment: No, my question is not about sending message from smartwatch to smartphone  - i know how to do it. I'm talking about intent mechanism for sharing data\message like if i want to send something using standalone app on my smartwatch like Facebook, Telegram or any other..

Comment: There's no reason that an arbitrary `Intent` shouldn't work on Wear, assuming there's an app installed that's registered to receive it. What happens when you try?

Comment: There are 2 different types of behavior:
1. In case of Intent with defined package name it's a blank activity, surely it's not a activity of initiated app - telegram, Facebook or other - it's a blank one.
2. In case of Intent without defined package name it's a standard system Toast with response - "There is no any app, who may work with this action".

Only intent with Call is working well, but it's not an intalled 3-d party app. After many tryings I have started thinking that Intent mechanism doesn't work for Wear 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After huge research and many tryings i can say, that Android wear app doesn't support any sharings with Telegram or Facebook. 
That's because Intent mechanism doesn't work for 3-d party app in Android Wear.